# How to change hyphen sign for question mark in java program?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, character-encoding

I'm utilizing this line codes

```
String string = "Some usefull information − don't know what happens with my output";
System.out.println(string);
String str2verify = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//someWellFormXpath")).getText();
Assert.assertEquals(str2verify , "Some usefull information − don't know what happens with my output");
```

And I'm getting this in my console, so if I want to use equals function doesn't work.

Output

```
Some usefull information ? don't know what happens with my output
expected [Some usefull information ? don't know what happens with my outputS] but found [Some usefull information − don't know what happens with my output]
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [Some usefull information ? don't know what happens with my outputS] but found [Some usefull information − don't know what happens with my output]
```

Comment: It seems that the `−` in your text is U+2212 which your console cannot display. That's an issue with your console, not your application.

Comment: But why whenever I debug it I also see this question mark symbol instead of minus sign?

Comment: You need to set the character set  ( UTF-8 is your friend) and/or font of your console app. Not a Java problem. See your code run successfully [at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/3lgMsg).

Comment: @cagoscra Alternatively, replace the symbol with the "normal" minus sign (U+002D, `-`)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I can do it but the assertion will still fail due different content in the web page.

Answer (score 1):

This is the process:

- You write some text. In an editor. That is showing strings to you.
- You save your file. files are **bytes**, not characters, so your editor is applying a charset encoding to do this. Which one? Your editor will know, you didn't mention which one you use so I can't tell you.
- Javac reads your file. files are **bytes**, but `javac` needs **characters**, so `javac` is applying a charset encoding to do this. Which one? "The platform default", unless you use the `-encoding` parameter / the tool you are using that calls `javac` has a way to tell it which `-encoding` parameter to use.
- Javac emits class files. These are byte based so this doesn't require encoding.
- Your `java` JVM runs your class file. As part of running, a string is printed to standard out.
- `System.out` refers to 'standard out'. These things are, on pretty much every OS, **a stream of bytes**. Meaning, when you send strings there, the JVM first encodes your string using some charset encoding, then it goes to standard out.
- Something is connected to the other end of standard out and sees these bytes. These convert the bytes back to a string, also using some encoding.
- The characters are sent to the font rendering engine on your OS. Even if the character 'survived' all those conversions back and forth, it is possible your font doesn't have a glyph for it. The intent is clearly for that character to be an emdash (a dash that is as long as the letter 'm' - the standard 'minus' character is an ndash, not the same thing; that one is a bit shorter).

Count em up - that's like 6 conversions. **They all need to be using the same charset encoding**. So, check that your editor and `javac` agree on what charset encoding your source file is in. Then, check that the console thing that is showing the string is in agreement with standard out (which should be 'platform default', whatever that might be), then, check if the font you use has emdash.

> `PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");`

Then write to `ps`, not `System.out` - that's how you can explicitly force some charset to be used when writing to output.

Comment: Excellent synopsis and explanation. One more note: Most defaults in Java 18 changed to UTF-8 rather than platform-specific. See [JEP 400: UTF-8 by Default](https://openjdk.org/jeps/400).

Comment: So what's the best I can do I'm using Assert.assertEquals() method from TestNG library to review the code from a web page? I'm receiving "Some usefull information − don't know what happens with my output but whenever I'm getting following AssertionError.

Comment: Trying with PrintStream only got following result

Comment: Some usefull information âˆ’ don't know what happens with my output

Comment: What if I was using windows-1252 or CP-1252, is it possible to change my console in intelliJ to that encoding, becaus IntelliJ was using that encoding to my whole project should I change it all to UTF-8?

Comment: How can I review all encoding for jvm, compiler and console?

Comment: Generally the right answer is to UTF-8 all the things. If you're writing tests, as long as your editor and `javac` agree, you're fine. It might not print properly but that's just an issue of the printing part (which isn't relevant for your webapp).

Answer (score 0):

It turns that em dash doesn't have a representation in cp-1252 charset encoding, so at the end I have to change to UTF-8 all my files in the project to be able to save this character.

It was a pain in the brain this encoding issue.

Thanks for all the suggestions friends.